# Cannot Login to Raspberry-Pi directly, but can access it via SSH

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, nfs, buildroot, nfsclient

I am booting the rootfs of my raspberry pi over NFS. (Local network static ip-s)

Raspberry mounts rootfs successfully and I can access it over ssh.
But I cannot log-in on the device itself via keyboard attach to it.

There are no error messages except when I type the password it fails to login

```
Welcome to Buildroot
buildroot login: root
Password:
Login timed out after 60 seconds
```

When I log in over ssh there are no issues what so ever. 
I do not see any process taking to much time

My steps to get to the setup were.

1. Mount rootfs partition of the sdcard.img to a directory exported by NFS
2. Modify the cmdline.txt on the sdcard to boot over nfs.

Answer (score 1):

So I just figured this one out in case someone has this trouble in the future (found it through a google search). Make sure you set your keyboard locale setup correctly. As the keys I thought were hitting were in fact not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue when I changed the password for default user and not able to ssh into raspi after that. But was able to login using raspi connected keyboard. @Justin has described it perfectly.

Issue is with the keyboard layout.

My raspi4 keyboard [shift + 2] = "

My Laptop keyboard [shift + 2] = @

Since we can't see the password entered while changing, we assume the password wrong.

Solution is a) change the keyboard layout for you raspi OR b) just check the keys you entered on command line.